# Show that $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $(Ax,x)$ is real for all x

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

> Let $A:X\rightarrow X$ be a linear transformation, where $X$ is a finite-dimensional complex inner product space. Show that $A$ is self-adjoint if and only if $(Ax,x)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in X$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> First let we suppose that $A$ is self-adjoint then,
>       \begin{eqnarray*}
>     (Ax,x)=(x,A^{*}x)=(x,Ax)=(\overline{Ax,x})
>  \end{eqnarray*}
>       which proofs that $(Ax,x)$ is real for all $x\in X$. Now let us prove 
>       that is sufficient. Let $(Ax,x)\in\mathbb{R},~\forall x\in X$,
>       \begin{eqnarray*}
>     (Ax,x)&=&(x,A^{*}x)=(\overline{A^{*}x,x})=(A^{*}x,x),~\forall x\in X\\
>     0&=&(C=(A-A^{*})x,x)
>  \end{eqnarray*}
>           then all we need to prove is that, $C\equiv 0$ first apply $C$ in 
>           $x+y$ to get
>   \begin{eqnarray}
>     0&=&(C(x+y),x+y)\Rightarrow (Cx,y)+(Cy,x)=0\\
>     0&=&(C(ix+y),ix+y)\Rightarrow (Cx,y)-(Cy,x)=0
>     \end{eqnarray}
>           then $$(Cy,x)=0,~\forall x,y\in X\Rightarrow C\equiv 0$$ or more precisely 
>           $A=A^{*}$.

Comment: Solid answer ... +1

Comment: Just thank you! I was speaking about you previous comment.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please explain.  I gave an up vote.